# Z-index on hover

Tags: javascript, html, hover, position, z-index

For a website I'm building I have an image with a light-grey h1 under it. When I hover over the image, the text should become black and the z-index should change so it sits above the image.

The colour change is working, z-index isn't. My h1 has position: relative added to it so that's not the issue.

```js
$('#photo').mouseover(function() {
  $('#title').css.zIndex = "100"
  $('#title').css("color", "#000000")
});
```

```css
#photo {
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#photo:hover {
  z-index: 4;
  position: relative;
}

.titles {
  position: relative;
}

#title {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="projects">
  <h1 class="titles" id="title">Title</h1>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/10158407872045403/picture?type=large" id="photo"></a>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively I've also tries using

```
$('#title').css("z-index", "0")
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I've converted your code blocks into a Stack Snippet (the `[<>]` toolbar button), but it doesn't replicate the color chane. Could you please edit so this is a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: `$('#title').css.zIndex = "100"` is incorrect but the `$('#title').css("z-index", "0")` you said you've tried is correct. (For assigning 0; perhaps 0 just isn't high enough?)

Comment: Also, where is the title under the image? `I have an image with a light-grey h1 under it.`

Comment: @gurvinder372: I assume the `h1` in the example is meant to be under the image, but the OP hasn't included the CSS to do that. ("Yet", hopefully.)

Comment: Yeah the "0" was a typo (I also included a mouseOut function so the text would go lightgrey again when you hover out of the image and accidentally copied that line instead of the mouseOver one), sorry guys. I just re-typed the entire thing exactly the same and all of a sudden it's working. So thank you guys! I'm good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#title').css.zIndex = "100"` is incorrect, but the `$('#title').css("z-index", "0")` you said you've tried is correct — it's just, you used `0` there instead of `100`. Since both the photo and title have `z-index: 0` and the photo is after the title, the photo wins.

If you use `$('#title').css("z-index", "100")`, it works (but keep reading):

```js
$('#photo').mouseover(function() {
  $('#title').css("z-index", "100");
  $('#title').css("color", "#000000")
});
```

```css
#photo {
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: -4em;
}

#photo:hover {
  z-index: 4;
  position: relative;
}

.titles {
  position: relative;
  color: grey;
}

#title {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="projects">
  <h1 class="titles" id="title">Title</h1>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/10158407872045403/picture?type=large" id="photo"></a>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

(I also added `top: -4em;` to the photo so it did actually overlap the title.)

---

Having said that, I would try to use CSS for this instead. If we give a class to the `a` wrapper around `img`, and we put the title *after* that rather than before it (since you're visually making them overlap anyway), we can use either an [adjacent sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) (`+`) or a [general (following) sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) (`~`) and a `:hover` pseudoclass:

```
.photo-wrapper:hover ~ h1.titles, h1.titles:hover {
  z-index: 100;
  color: black;
}
```

That automatically turns the title black and moves it up the z-order if the user hovers either the photo or the title:

```css
#photo {
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#photo:hover {
  z-index: 4;
  position: relative;
}

.titles {
  position: relative;
  color: grey;
}

#title {
  position: relative;
  top: -4em;
}

.photo-wrapper:hover ~ h1.titles, h1.titles:hover {
  z-index: 100;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="projects">
  <a href="#" class="photo-wrapper"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/10158407872045403/picture?type=large" id="photo"></a>
  <h1 class="titles" id="title">Title</h1>
</div>
```

---

Having said that, I wouldn't directly manipulate the style of `#title` like that, I'd use CSS combined with a class we use on `.projects`: